Multiple VideoView controls crash C# WinForms application LibVLCSharp
For a project I want 2 (or eventually more) videos to play in a C# WinForms application with LibVLCSharp. One instance of LibVLC with one instance of a MediaPlayer and one VideoView works without issues. However, when creating 2 MediaPlayers each connected to their own VideoView results in the application crashing mostly when I try to do an operation such as resizing the VideoViews.
Below is a sample of my code. To make this example work, 2 VideoView controls have to be added to the form.
public partial class Form6 : Form
{
    LibVLC libVLC;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer2;

    public Form6()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Core.Initialize();

        libVLC = new();

        mediaPlayer1 = new(libVLC);

        Media media1 = new(libVLC, new Uri(@"Path\to\some\video"));
        mediaPlayer1.Media = media1;
        media1.Dispose();

        videoView1.MediaPlayer = mediaPlayer1;

        mediaPlayer1.Play();

        mediaPlayer2 = new(libVLC);

        Media media2 = new(libVLC, new Uri(@"Path\to\some\video"));
        mediaPlayer2.Media = media2;
        media2.Dispose();

        videoView2.MediaPlayer = mediaPlayer2;

        mediaPlayer2.Play();
    }

    private void Form6_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        videoView1.Size = videoView2.Size = Size.Round(Size * 0.3f); 
        // Arbitrary values to force resize of videoView when resizing form
    }
}

Using the code above and quickly resizing the form continuously with the mouse causes the application to crash after anywhere from 0 to 10 seconds. This issue only occurs with 2 MediaPlayers and VideoViews playing media at the same time. The issue also persists when just resizing one of the VideoViews, but it does take longer for the crash to occur. I have tried to put each MediaPlayer on their own LibVLC instance, but with no effect. This is also discouraged by the LibVLCSharp documentation. Finally, I tried to control each MediaPlayer from a different thread using Task.Run(), in case that was an issue, but also without effect.
In all cases, there is no obvious error message in the LibVLCSharp logs and no debug error, the application just freezes and closes.
Any advice on this issue is greatly appreciated!

The Windows Event Log (Application) will probably show what happened.

Thanks a lot! There is indeed an error message in the log. The error message mentions a BEX64 error? I tried to run the application on a different computer (which I should probably have done earlier) and it seems to work fine so far... It does remain curious why everything works fine with only one VideoView though...
